# Removed WSP's features still showing in site collection in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, solution-package, features

some WSP's were deployed in SharePoint 2010 Farm and those WSPs have been completely removed from the Farm and not showing in "Manage Farm solution" section but those features (belong to WSP's) are still showing in site collections of Web applications in the deactivated mode.

Even if I create a new web application and create site collection but still those features are showing in new web app's site collections.
what is the issue why they still exist.

Comment: I try to use https://featureadmin.codeplex.com/ but it didn't help. So finally i tried below option in given URL and it worked. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32630.sharepoint-2013-cleanup-or-remove-missing-site-and-web-features-from-farm.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First try to find if the solution if still exist using `Get-SPSolution` command.
If still exist, then use the following:

```
Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity solution.wsp -allwebapplications
Remove-SPSolution -identity solution.wsp -force
```

You can use **Feature Admin** to remove orphaned features
https://featureadmin.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Prakash. If my answer above is resolve your issue please kindly marked as acceptable answer